# Intellij cannot resolve symbol in a config file using groovy syntax

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA CE 2016.3. I created a gradle project. My application uses a groovy based configuration file. I use `ConfigSluper` to read configuration parameters.

When I open the `config.groovy` file, the editor complains about `cannot resolve symbol [x]` error.

Does anyone know how to get the editor recognize groovy based configuration file syntax?

I attached 2 screenshots

[image: This is my configuration file]

[image: And this is the error message editor gives]

Comment: do you have the groovy support plugin enabled? (File > Settings > Plugins) Check for Groovy and/or Gradle... see if they are enabled

Comment: @ochi without Groovy plug-in enabled, there would be no syntax highlighting at all and Gradle plug-in will also disable automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This weak warning can be either ignored or [disabled](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/suppressing-inspections.html) as this inspection doesn't make sense for configuration files.

[image: warning]

Gradle scripts code insight in IntelliJ IDEA is not complete, there is an [open issue for that](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-50450).

Comment: Hi, I disabled the warnings but the highlighting is still not working. I have the groovy plugin and everything is just fine for my groovy classes. I've decided to use yaml for my config files. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Please clarify, your screenshot clearly shows that syntax highlighting works fine, otherwise there would be no colors in the file at all (compare to any Text file having similar contents).